How to add tspan to svg text
I have "multiline" svg text element with tspans as lines like this:
<svg>
  <text>
    <tspan x="50%" dy="1em">hello</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" dy="1em">world</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>

I want to append a line (as a tspan) to it like this:
let svgText = document.querySelector('text')
let tspan = document.createElement('tspan')
tspan.innerHTML = 'third line'
svgText.appendChild(tspan)

I can verify that it's actually appended and everything seems normal
console.log([...svgText.children].map(e => e.innerHTML))
console.log([...svgText.childNodes].map(e => e.nodeType))

But it's not visible and inspector says it has 0x0 size.
I tried to create text node and add it to tspan instead of using innerHTML but it has the same result.
I tried to change innerHTML of existing tspan and it worked as expected.
I tried to change x and dy attributes of tspan and it doesn't fix a problem.
codepen
What am I missing?

Try using createElementNS instead.
